# How to figure out when a HTML5 video player enters the full screen mode on iOS / iPads?

Tags: ios, html, video, mobile-safari, html5-video

The HTML5 `<video>` tag offers the user a button to toggle on and off the fullscreen mode on Safari for mobile devices (iOS).

I would like to capture and handle this user action but it doesn't seem to raise an event when the button is pressed and the player enters the full screen mode.

Here is the link to the Safari API for the HTMLVideoElement class:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkitjs/htmlvideoelement

We can easily find out when the video is paused of played in Javascript, like this:

```
function onload()
{
  var player = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];
  player.addEventListener('play',videoPlayHandler,false);
  player.addEventListener('pause',videoPauseHandler,false);
}
```

However they don't seem to have any events for when the video enters the full screen mode.

We can force the video into fullscreen mode in response to user action by calling the *webkitEnterFullscreen()*, but that doesn't help me.  I need to know when the user taps on the fullscreen button.

Hiding the controls and replacing them by my own custom controls sounds like a really long winded solution.

Another option I can think of is to set a timing event, constantly checking for the *webkitDisplayingFullscreen* property, but that feels like a bad thing to do in terms of memory management.

Can anyone suggest a better solution?

Comment: Further to what I said above, the Safari documentation mentions the event webkitfullscreenchange, but it doesn't seem to work on iPads.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450152/webkitfullscreenchange-event-not-firing-on-ipad

Answer (score 43, accepted):

After much faffing around a friend finally pointed me in the right direction.

The events I was looking for are: *webkitbeginfullscreen* and *webkitendfullscreen*

```
var player = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];
player.addEventListener('webkitbeginfullscreen', onVideoBeginsFullScreen, false);
player.addEventListener('webkitendfullscreen', onVideoEndsFullScreen, false);
```

With that I can safely capture when the user clicks over the fullscreen button on Safari for the iPads.  Interestingly the same events don't seem to work for Safari on the iMac (tested on version 5.1.2).

Thanks Apple for their inconsistency and hours of wasted time.

Comment: On desktop Safari, use the "webkitfullscreenchange" event, and check `document.webkitIsFullScreen` in the listener.

Comment: On Chrome check `document.getElementById('videoElement').webkitDisplayingFullscreen` and the event to listen is `webkitfullscreenchange` as on Safari.

Comment: `webkitDisplayingFullscreen` is deprecated.

Comment:  for you!!!, seriously wtf with safari, made me lose like 2 hours plus 15 stackoverflows questions until I arrive here. cheers bro!!

Comment: Do you know how to pause the playback while in fullscreen mode ? thanks

Comment: Could please send the documentation link here?