# How to disable default closing option in HTML 5 full screen mode

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using HTML 5 full screen API, When full screen mode is activated, there is this default option on the top of screen (see the image attached) which allows user to close full screen mode.

[image: default closing option that comes on the top of scrren]

Is there any way to hide/disable this? it looks really ugly and it is useless since I am using my own closing option. I am ok with javascript solution if there is any.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @BipinKumarPal how is that a solution?

Comment: you use jquery library than use my code

Comment: It's unlikely that this can be removed, as it is the browser's way of telling the user what is happening. Removing it would open the doors to all kinds of security-related shenanigans. We had that 10 years ago with IE 5's "chromeless windows" and it was a disaster and went away soon after

Comment: @Pekka웃 in that case is there any way to call a function on that (exit full screen) link?

Comment: No, but there seems to be a "cancel" API call: http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-full-screen-api/

Comment: @Pekka웃 then how can i change style of element if user exits full screen using esc or (exit full screen) link?

Comment: Not sure. There is `document.fullScreen` in the linked article - you may be able to frequently check for that and change stuff accordingly

Comment: @Pekka웃 damn, that is not a good way

Comment: @Pekka웃 if you are 100% sure, why don't you put your 1st comment in answer so i can accept it and close the question

Comment: @Pekka웃 apparently there is something called webkitfullscreenchange which can identify even if user ends full screen mode using default option provided by browser

Comment: Yeah, indeed: [How can we figure out when a HTML5 video player enters the full screen mode on iOS / iPads?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9094913) (will be limited to Chrome/Safari though)

Comment: @Pekka웃 thanks for assistance man, appreciate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unlikely that the browser notification can be removed, as it is the browser's way of telling the user what is happening. Removing it would open the doors to all kinds of security-related shenanigans.

We had that 10 years ago with IE 5's "chromeless windows" and it was a disaster and [went away soon after](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200511/no_more_chromeless_popup_windows) [[available at archive.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20150111090054/http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200511/no_more_chromeless_popup_windows)].