# Determine video fullscreen JavaScript HTML

Tags: javascript, html, video, fullscreen

I've been looking all over and couldn't find any concise information

Using JavaScript and HTML, how can I determine when a video becomes fullscreen?

How can I determine when the video leaves fullscreen?

Answer (score 2):

April 21, 2015 -- solution I found:

```
var video = document.querySelector("#myVideo");

video.addEventListener("webkitfullscreenchange", function (e) {
    console.log('isFullscreen ', e.target.webkitDisplayingFullscreen);
});
```

If you inspect the event object, you will see `bubbles: true`, meaning that all ancestor (window, document) nodes should also see the event, and the listener can be attached to them as well

---

`fullscreenchange` Event:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/fullscreenchange

---

Similar question:
[How to figure out when a HTML5 video player enters the full screen mode on iOS / iPads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9094913/how-can-we-figure-out-when-a-html5-video-player-enters-the-full-screen-mode-on-i)

Comment: Can you link to the documentation where you found this? Also with `webkitfullscreenchange` I have a feeling that it won't work cross-browser.

Comment: [fullscreenchange event MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/fullscreenchange), you need to add the appropriate browser prefix to the event name, see also [this](http://robertnyman.com/2012/03/08/using-the-fullscreen-api-in-web-browsers/)

Comment: Thanks guys, at my work we only support webkit browsers but yes, you would need to prefix correctly

Comment: @PatrickEvans I would highly recommend Kapeli Dash and mdn.io/yourQueryHere for quick documentation lookups ;)