# JWPlayer 7 wrong player status on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, jwplayer, jwplayer7

As you can see from screencast I want to play video on iPhone ( http://d.pr/v/1cran ) and I hit play it goes to native full screen, after I press done it goes back to browser but it still shows that video is playing. Can I catch the event when it goes from native fullscreen to browser that I could stop player manually. As you can see I show/hide text:

```
playerInstance.on('pause', function(event){
    $('#msg').show();
});
playerInstance.on('play', function(event){
    $('#msg').hide();
});
```

The problem is for mobile users that if they want to continue to see video again then need to press twice (once on stop button (I pressed the button on 9th second), then I need to press again on play button)

EDITED: I see somebody solved this problem with HTML5 video tag ( [How to figure out when a HTML5 video player enters the full screen mode on iOS / iPads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9094913/how-to-figure-out-when-a-html5-video-player-enters-the-full-screen-mode-on-ios) ) the problem is the same, but just with JWPlayer 7